# UITableView: I want to use an approach in which it is easy modify sections and rows (add, remove).

Tags: ios, uitableview

Our app has changed every month. It is very hard to modify sections and rows (add, remove). I need to scan every UITableViewDelegate's method and changed it. I'm using switch-case approach. I'm need more elegant approach.

I posted my code for two methods but in reality I have to modify 5 methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 NSInteger rows;

 switch (section) 
 {
    case 0:
    {
        rows = 3;
        break;
    }            
    case 1:
    {
        rows = 4;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        rows = 4;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        rows = 4;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        rows = 7;
        break;
    }

    default:
        rows = 1;
        break;
 }

 return rows;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 switch (indexPath.section) 
 {
    case 0:
    {
        switch (indexPath.section) 
        {
            case 0:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                break;
            }                    
            default:
                break;
        }

        break;            
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class say **TableManager**

Pass your table view to this class and let this class provide the data for all your tableviews. Differentiate between the tableviews by settings tag values to them.

So now you will have control of all your tableviews in this one class.

Instead of the numbers in the switch case use **enum**. It will increase readability in your code.

Depending upon your actual requirement you can manipulate this class's behavior from a plist perhaps.

Let me provide some code:

Define an enumerator

```
typedef enum { FIRST_TABLE, SECOND_TABLE, THIRD_TABLE } TableViews;


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

[TableManager getNumberOfRowsForTableView:tableView];

}
```

In your TableManager

```
+ (NSInteger)getNumberOfRowsForTableView:(UITableView*)theTableView
{

if(theTableView.tag == FIRST_TABLE) //FIRST_TABLE is an enum
{
 //Your conditions goes here
 return 3;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a .plist file where you can change directly its content and the `UIViewController` will just build his `UITableView` based on that. Work like a charm for me.

Answer (score -1):

I created this class that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/Morbix/TableManager

Basic Usage of TableManager

```
import TableManager // 1 - import TableManager

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let data = (1...1_000).map { "Row \($0)" }

        data.forEach { element in
            let row = tableView.addRow() // 2 - Add a row

            row.setConfiguration { (row, cell, indexPath) in // 3 - And configure it 
                cell.textLabel?.text = element
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

You can add Section and Rows, control the visibility, configure header and footer, etc...